# How to parse String HTML with Freemarker variables

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, freemarker

I am retrieving a String value from the database which contains a mix of HTML and Freemarker syntax.

Like so:

```
<p>${fragment.title}</p>
<table id='resultsTable' class='material-table'>
    <tr>
        <th>Instruction</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
Test
</table>
```

The following is how I access the above String in the Freemarker template:

```
<#include "inc/header.ftl">
<body>
<#include "inc/navigation.ftl">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <#if fragments??>
            <#list fragments as fragment>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="fragment">
                        ${fragment.design?html}
                    </div>
                </div>              
            </#list>
        </#if>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
<#include "inc/footer.ftl">
```

But the output is not quite right:

```
<p>${fragment.title}</p> <table id='resultsTable' class='material-table'> <tr> struction</th> </th> </tr> ddd </table>
```

How do I use Freemarker to parse the HTML and parse the value of `${fragment.title}` at the same time?

Comment: can you try to use  `parse=true` option for include? like `<#include "inc/header.ftl" parse=true>`

Comment: It is the Freemarker variables within the `fragment.design` String that aren't being parsed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `${fragment.design?html}`, use `<@fragment.design?interpret />`.

Related documentation:

- `?interpret`: http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_expert.html#ref_builtin_interpret
- `?html`, that you don't need here: 
  http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_html

Note that if you need to run a lot of `?interpret`-s per second, and you tend to interpret the same strings again and again in your templates, you might need some custom solution that caches and reuses the `Template`-s made from those strings. But, in most applications, performance is not an issue with `?interpret`.

BTW, you don't need that `#if fragments??` if you use `<#list fragments! as fragment>` (note the `!`).

Answer (score 2):

**Option one**: Process your string in java controller. This way you don't need to change template

```
@RequestMapping("/test2")
public ModelAndView test2() throws IOException, TemplateException {
    Map<String, String> fragment = new HashMap<>();
    fragment.put("title", "Some Title");
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("index", "fragment", fragment);

    //your string should go here instead of this default
    String template = "<div>${fragment.title}</div> <div>some other test</div>";
    fragment.put("design", processTemplate(model.getModel(), template));

    return model;
}

private String processTemplate(Map model, String template)
        throws IOException, TemplateException {
    Template t = new Template("TemplateFromDBName", template,
            Environment.getCurrentEnvironment().getConfiguration());
    Writer out = new StringWriter();
    t.process(model, out);
    return out.toString();
}
```

Template part:

```
<div class="fragment">
    ${fragment.design}
</div>
```

---

**Option two**: Create custom  [method expression](http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_datamodel_method.html) that you can use in template.

```
// http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_datamodel_method.html
public static class ProcessString implements TemplateMethodModelEx {

    public static final String PROCESS_STRING_FUNCTION_NAME = "processString";

    public TemplateModel exec(List args) throws TemplateModelException {
        if (args.size() != 1 ) throw new TemplateModelException("Wrong arguments");

        try {
            Environment env = Environment.getCurrentEnvironment();
            Template t = new Template("TemplateFromDBName", 
                    args.get(0).toString(), env.getConfiguration());

            Writer out = new StringWriter();
            t.process(env.getDataModel(), out);
            return new SimpleScalar(out.toString());
        } catch (IOException | TemplateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return new SimpleScalar("");

    }
}
```

Register it in configuration

```
@Configuration
public class FreeMarkerConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public FreeMarkerConfigurer freemarkerConfig( ) {
        FreeMarkerConfigurer freeMarkerConfigurer = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
        // some other config here

        Map properties = new HashMap();
        properties.put(ProcessString.PROCESS_STRING_FUNCTION_NAME,
                new ProcessString());

        freeMarkerConfigurer.setFreemarkerVariables(properties);
        return freeMarkerConfigurer;
    }
}
```

And template will look like:

```
<div class="fragment">
    ${processString(fragment.design)}
</div>
```

But controller will be clean

```
@RequestMapping("/test")
public ModelAndView test() throws IOException, TemplateException {
    Map<String, String> fragment = new HashMap<>();
    fragment.put("title", "Some Title");
    fragment.put("design", "<div>${fragment.title}</div><div> other test</div>");
    return new ModelAndView("index", "fragment", fragment);
}
```